# risk with returning strdup from a function with return type as char *?

Tags: c++, c, strdup

If I want to return strdup from a function whose return type is char*, then what are the risks or chances of memory leak ?

```
char* fun () {
    return strdup("hello");
}

int main() {
    for(;;)
    printf("%s\n", fun());
}
```

Comment: There is no risk, you HAVE a memory leak (unless you have some GC running).

Comment: But a memory leak does not result from calling `strdup` but rather from NOT calling `free` on the returned pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strdup()` returns a pointer to newly-allocated memory that must be freed later with `free()`.  You'll leak memory if you don't call `free()` on it — which, in your example, you don't.

Comment: Is this Fine:
`int main() {
  for(;;) {
    char* test = fun();
    printf("%s\n", test);
    free(test);
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You return an heap-allocated `char` pointer as an rvalue, so the user may forget to free it, as seen in the example you gave.

```
printf("%s\n", fun()); // memory leak

// this is fine
char* string = fun();
printf("%s\n", string);
free(string);
```

Better ask for a pointer to `char*` in parameter and allocated it.

If you really want to return a pointer like this and uses C++, you can use a `std::unique_ptr<char>` with a custom deleter which will `free` the string when you've finished with it.

```
unique_ptr<char, void (*)(char *)> fun () {
    return {strdup("hello"), std::free};
}
// then you can use it
printf("%s\n", &*fun());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the man page:

> The strdup() function returns a pointer to a  new  string  which  is  a
>      duplicate  of the string s.  Memory for the new string is obtained with
>      malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3).

so... strdup allocates memory that you must free, i.e. you have the ownership.

Answer (score 0):

The risk is indirect. If somebody warned you of using it, it is probably because `strdup` calls malloc and this call is not explicitly seen in the source code. So, theoretically, if somebody implements its own implementation of malloc later and will try catch all allocations made by your program, this one will not be catched.